# NHibernate and NTier Application

Tags: nhibernate, dto, n-tier-architecture

We want to use NHibernate for our persistency service.
Couple of questions:

1. if we load POCO using nhibernate, moving it to another tier, update it there (add items to bag or change some properties) and then return it to the persistency layer and save it, how does NHibernate know how to update the changes? (maybe something like select and compare the updated item with the previous one?)
2. Can we ask NHibernate to update only specific items? (in case we know the changes using some change tracker)
3. Do you know some library or pattern for POCO change tracker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- interesting approach for disconnected entity changes: http://ayende.com/blog/2275/disconnected-mode-change-tracking
- for detached entities

  ```
  // for single objects:
  // does load the object with the same Id from db and does copy all values over and returns the tracked entity
  var trackedentity = session.Merge(obj);
  ```
- changetracking with INPC: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/10/turbo-nhibernate-with-domain-invaders.html . i do not know ready to use libraries for change tracking

the second is by far the easiest but has some limitations

Answer (score 0):

In web service applications i usually don't expose the domain entities to service clients, all entities are mapped to DTO classes. Updates are done by retrieving the domain entity from the database, updating its properties from the calling parameter(s) and saving it, all in one transaction. To avoid writing lots of manual property assignments you could use something like AutoMapper to update domain entities from DTOs.

The same could be done for a service layer inside an application.